# How to find which styles are defined for an element

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, styles, flex4.5

I'm trying to figure out how to get a definition of all the style properties defined for an element (a skin component, to be exact), but I can't seem to find any solid means to do so.

Is there some native method that returns a merged style declaration for an ***instance*** rather than a `String` selector?

**UPD: Example**

Sample CSS would be something like:

`.a
{
someProperty: "someValue";
}`

Then later, the class "a" is applied to some element, say `s|Button`, that has a skin. The skin has a property also named `someProperty`, which should be "auto-filled" from the CSS style declaration, but in order to do that, the class has to go over all the properties defined for it and try to apply the value to the corresponding instance property.

Now, the problem I'm trying to figure out is **getting** the list of defined properties for the specific instance.

Comment: There is no native method. Will you want get all custom css declarations for any component?

Comment: Yes, if that means providing an **instance** as reference, but not a selector string - I've figured that one out already. 'Cause sometimes a CSS property is inherited from parent classes, and I am having lots of trouble collecting the summarized list of all the properties defined for the specific element instance.

Comment: Can you show an example, where you have problem with css?

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want two ways of setting property values, to a skin. And, if a style property with the same name as a property in the skin exists, then the value of the style property should be assigned.

One way to do this, is to create a skin method which checks if a style property with a specific name exists (i.e. a style which has that property applied to it contains that property). It could look something like this:

```
private function checkProperties(properties:Array)
{
    for each (var property:String in properties)
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(property) && getStyle(property))
            this[property] = getStyle(property);
}
```

Later on, you can call this method when the skin dispatches its "initialize" event:

```
<s:Skin initialize="checkProperties(["someProperty", "someProperty2", "someProperty3"])" />
```

Have a great day! Let us know if you need additional details.

Comment: Hmm, it never occurred to me that I can go the other way around and resolve values by the instance properties rather than by CSS style declaration. That's a good one! Much obliged!